# Same SKU but different product - Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I am facing a problem with the Products in a website made with Drupal 7 and Drupal Commerce.

As per the requirement, two admin can create products in the website with Same SKU and same name. But the difference will be the Stock number and the color etc.

As an example, 
Product A has SKU: 0001

The 1st admin Creates Product A with Price $10 and stock 10.
The 2nd admin Creates the Same product with Same SKU with Price $20 and stock 5.

Is it possible to do? Or it's better to create new SKU each time? Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a general commerce concept, which is not specific for Drupal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No, SKUs must be unique.

**Longer answer:**
SKU is acronym for Stock Keeping Unit. It is a specific produkt that you have have on stock, like a gray medium sized T-shirt with V-neck for men. Had it had a different size, color ... it would have been an entirely different product.

SKU's were create to be able to keep track of these different products, even if there only is a slight change. This also means that SKUs must be unique, since a SKU is the code for a specific product.

The above is general for e-commerce and originates from physical stores with stock keeping etc. Drupal Commerce conforms to these standards, and so it is impossible to create two products with the same SKU.

Comment: thanks again. I was in a doubt about the SKU. This helped me to give a good explanation to my Client.